# html image center but keep little bottom margin?

Tags: html, css, image, margin

I just have a little problem with an image bottom margin.

I don't understand why below the image, we have a little space with the menu. Someone can explain me why ? I want to stick my menu with my image but i can't and i don't know why.

Like you can see in my fiddle, i have already tried to put margin,padding,border=0 but no change.

Here my example : https://fiddle.jshell.net/3s6dv7rk/

Comment: you can define `float: left` to img style

Comment: I am getting no space

Answer (score 2):

Add display Block on image

```
display: block;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this fiddle : https://fiddle.jshell.net/3s6dv7rk/1/

Try this :

```
<img style="width:100px;height:40px;display: flex;" alt="Ludo et Béné"/>
```